# composer require silex.phar

Tags: silex, composer-php

Is it possible to require the latest stable silex.phar from within composer?

I found silex/silex dev-master / 1.0.x-dev on packagist but that seems to be the latest unfolded silex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point it isn't possible. Maybe/probably one day it will be, but I can't say when. That said, having "unfolded" code isn't such a big issue I'd think?

Comment: yes its not possible since phars fetched as repositories/dist get extracted.
there is a PR to prevent such behaviour: https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/537
but as Igor states in the comment this could result in troubles with dependencies included in the phar and others from composer.
well i guess i go unfolded ;), phars seemed so handy thou

Comment: We'll see later if we can add support for packaged phars because it'd be nice, but it needs some thinking to come up with a foolproof solution.